# Including .jar files in a classpath

Tags: java, jdbc, jar, classpath

I'm trying to get JDBC up and running in the Windows environment. What does it mean to include a .jar file in the classpath? I see how to modify the CLASSPATH environment variable for Windows... But what files need to go where and what does the CLASSPATH environment variable need to be set to? I've tried just about every combination that I can immediately think of, and I'm at a loss.

Thanks.

Comment: The classpath contains individual jar files and directories. In Java 6+ wildcards can be used as well. Setting the CLASSPATH environment variable can cause unexpected consequences; in a batch file it's ok, otherwise just use the -cp option.

Comment: I'm Java illiterate, and trying to get my feet off the ground. I checked the Oracle documentation, and they don't mention what the -cp option is, much less how it's used. Where can I go for that kind of information? Thank you very much!

Comment: The documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#options

Answer (score 2):

The CLASSPATH variable contains a list of directories where class files are found.  A .jar file is really a zipped up directory, so the name of the .jar file itself should be in the CLASSPATH, not the name of the directory it is in.

If, for example, you had two directories with class file trees in them `C:\java\classes\` and `C:\java\specialclasses\` and two jar files `C:\java\jars\jam.jar` and `C:\java\jars\jelly.jar` then your class path variable would be set to `C:\java\classes\;C:\java\specialclasses\;C:\java\jars\jam.jar;C:\java\jars\jelly.jar`

As a general rule, unless you have two packages with classes with the same name (which hopefully you don't), then you just want to add things that are going to commonly be used to the CLASSPATH variable and not remove or replace things which are already there.  By default, it includes the directories of the java.* classes, which are kind of important to include.  Also, depending on your environment, other commonly used classes may have been added by an administrator.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I must be missing something stupid... I have the CLASSPATH environment variable set to -> C:\Users\Jon\JavaProjects\TestProject\src\;C:\Users\Jon\JavaProjects\jars\mysql-connecter-java-5.1.18-bin.jar\ , and I'm still getting the ClassNotFoundException... Any idea?

Comment: You don't want a \ after the mysql-connecter-java-5.1.18-bin.jar  Putting a backslash afterwards makes it assume that it's literally a directory, but it's actually a file.  So when it looks for a directory with that name, it doesn't find one.  Remove that backslash and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

[Look no further than Oracle's own documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html)

For instance, if you had 3 jars in /a/directory, you would do something like:

```
java -classpath /a/directory/jar1.jar;/a/directory/jar2.jar;/a/directory/jar3.jar
```

You would set the CLASSPATH variable in a similar fashion.